# GDB debugging, detaching after fork from child process, so how can I do to exit GDB or continue with it?

Tags: linux, gdb

I am using GDB debugging, it shows "Detaching after fork from child process.." so in this case, how can I get out of GDB, or continue with it? Because I cannot get any response for whatever command I enter.
And, even if I set follow-fork-mode parent, it also shows the information above.
Thanks.

In this case, I want to set breakpoint in other places and continue the debugging.

Comment: It _sounds_ like you want `set follow-fork-mode child`, but hard to tell since you haven't described what it is you are doing.

Comment: GDB will announce the fork and detach from the child process, and then resume the parent process.  Unless the parent stops for some other reason then it is still running.  You can interrupt it with the keyboard interrupt, usually Ctrl-C which should return you to a `(gdb)` prompt.